# Email message not inside Gmail inbox or anywhere except search

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Somehow several emails get not delivered to my Gmail inbox, but are available within search for the sender. If I click on "all message" they will be inside the list but have no label like e.g. "inbox".

They however have one thing in common, all those "lost" emails are from my internal domain like support@domain..

What could be the reason for this? The filters do not imply any sorting of this specific emails.

Comment: Is the sender of that email messages connected in anyway with your account? Did you set a "send as" email account for your Gmail account? Is you account a Google common account or a G Suite account?

Comment: are you using categories?